# Creating a JSON enabled WCF Svc service manually

Tags: c#, wcf, json

How do I create a proper JSON enabled WCF svc service by overriding the createhost function?

Here's what I've tried...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WcfJsonServiceToGetImages
{
    public class Class1 : WebScriptServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {    
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1),baseAddresses);
           foreach(Uri uri in baseAddresses)
            {       
          WebHttpBinding webbinding=new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);
            webbinding.AllowCookies=true;
            webbinding.CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled=true;
            EndpointAddress ea=new EndpointAddress(uri);           
            WebHttpBehavior behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
            behavior.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
            behavior.DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped;      
            behavior.HelpEnabled = true;               
            behavior.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
           ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), webbinding, uri);
           endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);         
          }            
            return host;        
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the content of my svc file..

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfJsonServiceToGetImages.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="WcfJsonServiceToGetImages.Class1" %>
```

The interface and implemented class contain default code generated while creating a new WCF svc service.It's totally untouched.
Please guide me on getting this custom service host factory to work to host a JSON service.

Edit:I basically want to be able to access the service through http://localhost:portno/service1.svc/js

Thanks so much.

Comment: And what is that doesn't work? Do you get errors? XML instead of JSON? What's the real question here?? Your code looks OK at first sight...

Comment: ok,I actually am not getting any JSON output.It keeps saying endpoints dont match,etc etc...I'm getting error after error.I basically want to know how to make this overrided function work.I believe there might be lots of WCF experts here...

Comment: Show us the server config, and how does your *.svc file look like, and where does it live? If endpoints don't match, it's typically about addresses and/or bindings. You showed us only your server code - we can't really find out if the client side matches what you're trying to do here!

Comment: I'm not using any settings in the Web.Config.I'll post my svc file content and the interface...

Comment: The interface and class have the default code...it's untouched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution...
I had to use WebScriptEnablingBehavior instead of WebHttpBehavior.

Here's the working code....Hope it saves time for someone....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WcfJsonServiceToGetImages
{
    public class Class1 : WebScriptServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {    
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1),baseAddresses);
           foreach(Uri uri in baseAddresses)
            {       
          WebHttpBinding webbinding=new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);
            webbinding.AllowCookies=true;
            webbinding.CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled=true;
            EndpointAddress ea=new EndpointAddress(uri);           
            WebScriptEnablingBehavior behavior = new WebScriptEnablingBehavior();
            behavior.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
           // behavior.DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest;      



            behavior.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
           ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), webbinding, uri);
           endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);         
          }            
            return host;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so this means you are calling this from an Ajax or jQuery style client? That crucial information should really have been part of your original post.....

Comment: no,I couldn't access the json code by putting /js or /jsdebug.
Only after this modification,that works.I hope i sound a bit more clearer now...